# Is rolling a six sided dice 100 times return the same value as rolling a 100 sided die once? [Python]

Tags: python, function, math, random, dice

So I am making a function in python that simulates dice rolls based on user input. I have 2 versions of the code, one that uses a loop and one that is pure math(which I'm not sure is correct).

```
# Loop
def simulate_dice_loop(num, sides):
    result = 0
    while num > 0:
      x = random.randint(1, sides)
      result += x
      num -= 1
    return result
```

```
# Math
def simulate_dice_math(num, sides):
    max = num * sides
    result = random.randint(1, max)
    return result
```

I'm highly suspicious if the math one is correct, especially on larger numbers. The `loop dice roll` tends to stay around half of the max value. However, the `math` one tends to fluctuate all the time, sometimes even reaching 90% of max-- which is probably highly unlikely on normal occassions.

...Please help on how I could improve the `math` one because the loop tends to take longer the larger the number-- and also, to satisfy my curiosity on the subject. Thanks ^^

Comment: I assume you mean a 600-sided die, but it's not the same. The smallest value 100 six-sided dice can produce is 100, but a 600-sided dice can produce the numbers 1-99. Also the distributions are very different. Even in the simple case of 2 six-sided dice, the roll of 2 occurs with probability 1/36 (1+1), whereas a roll of 7 occurs with probability 1/6 (1+6 or 2+5 or 3+4 or 4+3 or 5+2 or 6+1).

Comment: Sometimes, reasoning with limit cases can help: would it be the same to 'roll' a one sided dice six times, or a six sided dice one time?

Comment: Hmm... I should probably just opt for the loop one to be more reliable just as long as I limit it at some point

Comment: I strongly advise not to call a variable `max`. This is already the name of a builtin function in python. See the list of builtin functions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html Assigning something else to a name in that list can have unintended consequences.

Comment: Ohh-- I renamed it from max_roll to max because it's easier to write.... that's great to know, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because for the math one, the chance to be max (num = 100,side = 6) is 1/600 while for the loop one, it is (1/6) **100 (approximately 1.5306467e-78 which is many times lower, correct me if I'm wrong).

And to improve the time(I'm assuming you are improving the loop one) , you can use list comprehension ( `sum([random.randint(1,side) for i in range(num)])`)

Comment: Yup, you're right. Although I asked this question to know the answer for the math one, to find how to compute the score using probabilities which I am not quite sure how

Comment: You can improve even more by **not** building a list at all: `sum(random.randint(1,side) for i in range(num))`. The only apparent difference is a pair of `[ ]`, but it avoids building the list and is more efficient.

Comment: Ohh~ After mulling over how that piece of code worked, I can only express my thanks on this newfound knowledge... thanks, @Stef! I'm pretty sure I'll use it a lot